# Ckeditor Outline in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, ckeditor

If anyone has figured out how to remove the outline that Chrome & Safari add on focus to a textarea, specifically in ckeditor, I'd love to hear it. I've applied multiple variants of "outline:none" to:

1. A custom CSS file I defined in config.js
2. The editor.css file of the skin I'm using
3. The main CSS file of the actual page

Nothing works, found a suggestion here http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17983 that claimed to work, but no dice.

Comment: Did you read all the way down on [http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17983](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17983)? The last post mentions that it won't work if you don't include `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the game on this one, but I found this question while trying to solve the problem on my own.

Luckily, I was able to figure it out.

```
.cke_focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

The .cke_focus class is added to the element via javascript whenever it has focus.

I added this into my own stylesheet which is called after the one included with CKEditor. If you need to, you can always up the specificity, but you shouldn't need to.